# FBAR reporting for non-resident aliens with single-member LLC

Tags: united-states, non-resident, small-business, limited-liability-company, fbar

(1) According to the FinCen's [FBAR filing instructions](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/FBAR%20Line%20Item%20Filing%20Instructions.pdf),

> "Any US person that has a financial interest in or signature authority
>   over foreign financial accounts must file an FBAR..."

This implies that *non-resident aliens* are excluded from FBAR filing requirements.

(2) However, a LLC is considered an US person as stated in the same source.

> "A person means an individual and legal entities including, but not
>   limited to, a limited liability company..."

This implies that *non-resident aliens*, when member of an LLC, are required to file an FBAR, even without [substantial presence](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test) in the US during the tax year in scope ([negative SPT](https://www.irstaxapp.com/use-substantial-presence-test-calculator/)).

(3) Regarding single-member LLCs, the [IRS states that](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/single-member-limited-liability-companies)

> "An LLC with only one member is treated as an entity disregarded  as
>   separate from its owner for income tax purposes (*but as a separate entity for purposes of employment tax and certain excise taxes*)"

**This is where the confusion starts.**

Based on the above facts, it is unclear in which way a *non-resident alien* is required to file the FBAR when owning a single-member LLC.

**QUESTIONS:**

**1. Does the LLC owner file the FBAR as a person (i.e. non-resident alien), listing all his foreign accounts?**

- In this case, there is no SSN/ITIN/EIN involved. How would the IRS then reference this back to the LLC?
- Worst case scenario is that the LLC violates its filing requirements and penalties are due.

**2. Does the owner file the FBAR as LLC entity, referencing the LLC's EIN?**

- In this case, it is unclear if the LLC "has a financial interest in or signature authority over" the private foreign accounts of its owner, as the LLC is ONLY disregarded separate from its owner "*for income tax purposes*" and FBAR reporting is not connected to the LLC's income tax return (see above).
- Again, worst case is that the LLC violates its filing requirements by not listing those accounts and penalties are due.

**Do non-resident aliens with a single-member LLC file their FBAR on an individual level or on a LLC level, or both?**

Comment: Although those instructions are linked from the IRS website, they are actually from _FinCEN_: notice the title and logo (which is not the IRS logo), and the URL host is www.fincen.gov -- and the filing (if you do so) is also to FinCEN not IRS. Personally to be safe I would report as the entity and let them decide whether to ignore it; since it's (now) online the only cost is a little time.